# Getting the path of a txt file in a src folder so i can read from it into an array

Tags: java, android

I have a text file, that I am trying to convert to a String array (where each line is an element of the array).
I have found a code here that seems to do this perfectly, the only problem is, even when I use the relative path of the file, I get a FileNotFoundException.
The relative file path:

```
String path = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/app/src/main/res/raw/" 
+ getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.raw.txtAnswers);
```

When I try to use this path in a reader

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try{
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
......
```

The path is underlined in red and says FileNotFoundException.
Perhaps it is expecting another type of path (not relative?) or did I get the path wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The relative file path

That is not a file path.

> Perhaps it is expecting another type of path

`res/raw/...` is a file on your hard drive. It is *not* a file on the device.

To access raw resources, use `getResources()` (called on any `Context`, like an `Activity` or `Service`) to get a `Resources` object. Then, [call `openRawResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29), passing in your resource ID, to get an `InputStream` on that resource's contents.

Comment: res/raw/... is a file on your hard drive. It is not a file on the device - I was using "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+", so I guess this gets me to the actual relative path on the device, but how do i go further from there? what is the equivalent of res/raw?

Comment: @user2896061: "I guess this gets me to the actual relative path on the device" -- no, it does not. There is no path on the device, because there is no file on the device. Resources are entries in the APK file; you access them through the `Resources` object or various helper methods (e.g., `getString()` on `Activity`).

Comment: Oh, okay, I understand now! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

According to me the best way would be to past that `txt` file in `assets` folder of your source code.
To use that `File` just use the following snippet:

```
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("YOUR_TEXT_FILE");
```

It returns `InputStream` which further can be used to read the `File` & convert the data into a `Array`

Comment: I already have an inputStream from the file, but I just can't figure out how to convert the data into a String array

Comment: And you post small part of your text file, I feel if your data is separated by new line or comma then go for using `StringTokenizer`